# Constructing Vector Spaces from Linear Combinations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I've modified parts of this quote from *"Introduction to Linear Algebra by Strang"*, for brevity in the questions below. If the quote itself seems illogical or incorrect in any form, please inform me and I will make the necessary edits.

> - The linear combination of *one* vector in $\mathbb{R^n}$ will always *fill* out a line ($\mathbb{R^1}$)
> - The linear combination of *two* vector in $\mathbb{R^n}$ will always *fill* out a plane ($\mathbb{R^2}$)
> - The linear combination of *vectors* vector in $\mathbb{R^n}$ will always *fill* out a three-dimensional space ($\mathbb{R^3}$)

When Strang talks about *filling* a line, plane, etc. what he is really referring to is actually *constructing* vector spaces from linear combinations correct?

If so, then am I correct in saying that the linear combination of $m$ vectors where each vector $v \in \mathbb{R^n}$, will create a $m$-dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R^m}$. where $\mathbb{R^m}$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$, i.e. $\mathbb{R^m} \subset \mathbb{R^n}$.

Again if I'm correct is the below a correct mathematical translation of what I've just stated above?

$$\text{Given} \ \left(\ \mathbb{R^m} =\ \sum_{i=1,\ \ j=1}^{m} \lambda_j\cdot v_i \ \ \text{where} \ \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, v \in \mathbb{R^n}\right) \implies \mathbb{R^m} \subset \mathbb{R^n}$$

Lastly does this notion of construction vector spaces from linear combinations generalize to arbitrary fields $\mathbb{F}$ and arbitrary vectors spaces $\mathbb{F^n}$? Does the generalization below hold true?

$$\text{Given} \ \left(\ \mathbb{F^m} =\ \sum_{i=1,\ \ j=1}^{m} \lambda_j\cdot v_i \ \ \text{where} \ \lambda \in \mathbb{F}, v \in \mathbb{F^n}\right) \implies \mathbb{F^m} \subset \mathbb{F^n}$$

Comment: If you have $m$ *linearly independent* vectors in $K^n$ (for any field $K$) then their span is a $m$-dimensional subvector space. Moreover any $m$-dimensional vector space is isomorphic to $K^m$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost right, but there is just two point that you should check:

The first one is that if you have $m$ vectors it will generate an $m$-dimensional space if and only if the vectors are lineary independent.

The second one is that actually is not $\mathbb R^m\subset\mathbb R^n$, but what you get is $\sum^m_{i=1}\lambda_i v_i=W\subset\mathbb R^n$, and $W\cong\mathbb R^m$, note that is not the same as $W=\mathbb R^m$.